# How to combine data from two endpoints via observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a setup on the backend where I fetch users info from one endpoint and their profile photos from another one.

I need to first fetch users and then their photos before displaying anything on the screen.

I've got a following interface

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  photoUrl?: string;
}
```

and two functions that return observables: `getUsers` and `getUserPhoto`.

I make the call like so:

```
this.getUsers().pipe(
  map((users: User[]) => {
    return users.forEach(user => {
      // this part is problematic as I don't know how to call it properly
      return this.getUserPhoto(user.id)
    })
  })
);
```

Ideally, the end result of this call should be a `User` array with all properties including `photoUrl`.

Comment: use pipe on map and inside map operator, use Array.map().

Comment: can you please show an example? It's unclear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
this.getUsers.pipe(
    switchMap(users => {
        return forkJoin(users.map(user => this.getPhoto(user.userPhotoUrl).pipe(map(photo => ({...user, photo})))))
})
)
```

you will have an array of users with `photo` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat operator from rxjs to chain your api calls, follow this link for more details :
 https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Comment: I don't think it works in my case. Because the second http call result should update the results of the first http call, and not just concatenate results of two http calls.